# Render custom json polymorphic list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a /tags.json where i want to render a list of players and teams, using the following which i have put in both players and teams model.

```
def token
  "#{id}_#{self.class.name}"
end
```

Tags controller

```
def index
  @players = Player.all
  @teams = Team.all
  @tags = @teams + @players

  respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: @tags}
  end
end
```

But how can i create a list in my tags controller, so i can get something like this

```
[
    {"name":"Bob","token":"1_Player"},
    {"name":"Yankees","token":"1_Team"}
]
```

How can i do this?

**Edit**

```
format.json { render json: @tags.as_json(only: [:name])}
```

renders

```
[
    {"name":"Bob"},
    {"name":"Yankees"}
]
```

But how could i get token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@tags = []
Team.all.each do |team|
  @tags.push({name: team.name, tag: team.token})
end
Player.all.each do |player|
  @tags.push({name: player.name, tag: player.token})
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @tags}
end
```